# Difference between values of logs["accuracy"] and epoch accuracy

Tags: keras, callback, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I use googlecolab to train my LSTM model. To save accuracy and loss I create custom call back:

```
class CustomSaveMetric(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    file_path = os.path.join(G_drive_path, checkpoint_folder_name)
    with open(file_path + ".txt", "a+", encoding="UTF-8") as metric_writer:
      metric_writer.write(f"{logs['loss']}-{logs['accuracy']}\n")
    print(f"Loss and Accuracy is saved in text file.")
```

At the end of the 200 epochs, my best accuracy is 0.5935 but when I print the value in a custom call back or I use my txt file which the accuracy and loss save on its values are different. in the text file, the max accuracy is 0.579771. why value in logs["accuracy"] and the value print in each epoch is deferent, what can I do to create the same values?
for example the last epoch result:

```
3758/3758 [==============================] - 178s 47ms/step - loss: 1.8448 - accuracy: 0.5935
```

logs["accuracy"] value show 0.579771